# Embedded homology sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $Y$ be a rational homology three sphere, and  $Y\hookrightarrow S^1\times S^3$ a smooth embedding.

> **Q.** Can we say that $[Y]$ is a generator of $H_3(S^1\times S^3;\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: Of course not.  Perhaps you mean to ask a more refined question?

Answer (score 7):

If it's nonseparating, then it is a generator.  This is a straightforward consequence of Poincare duality.  If it separates then of course it is 0 in homology.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $Y$ is the standard three sphere. Since $S^1\times S^3$ is a four dimensional manifold, it contains an embedded $\mathbb{R}^4$ (a chart). Just embed $Y$ into this $\mathbb{R}^4$.